# Latex - \multicolumn within an align* environment

Tags: latex, equations

I would like to have a \multicolumn like effect within an align* environment, as shown in the code snippet (which doesn't work) below. I.e., I want the text to be aligned with the leftmost column, but it shouldn't affect the alignment characteristics of the equation otherwise. \intertext{...} unfortunately flushes everything to the left margin, even when the equation is centered.

```
    \begin{align*}
      1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
      \multicolumn{5}{l}{Some text that I want to appear here..} \\
      %\intertext{Some text that I want to appear here} \\
      7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12
    \end{align*}
```

How do I make this happen?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: You can find a whole community at [tex.stackexchange.com](http://tex.stackexchange.com), where no TeX question is too small.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 8):

```
\begin{align*}
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 \\
  \omit\rlap{Some text that I want to appear here...}\\
  7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12
\end{align*}
```

Generally, as a replacement for `\multicolumn` within align-like environments, one could try to experiment with `\multispan`, but it seems to interfere badly with the alignment in this case.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently in math mode, the commands \llap and \rlap for horizontal alignment don't work. The package mathtools provides \mathllap and \mathrlap, which do work there.

Source: [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/278/can-i-use-clap-rlap-and-llap-in-math-mode).